# android : media player - pause called in state 8

Tags: android

I am using the media player in my app for some short sounds. Though I do not find any problem / crash in my app, I could see some of the following error messages.. Please help me to resolve this.

```
03-23 22:53:16.229: E/MediaPlayer(19185): pause called in state 8
03-23 22:53:16.229: E/MediaPlayer(19185): error (-38, 0) 
03-23 22:53:16.449: E/MediaPlayer(19185): Error (-38,0)
03-23 22:53:16.449: D/OpenGLRenderer(19185): Flushing caches (mode 0) 
03-23 22:53:16.459: D/OpenGLRenderer(19185): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-23 22:53:17.759: D/OpenGLRenderer(19185): Flushing caches (mode 0) 
03-23 22:53:17.809: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(19185): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
03-23 22:53:17.809: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(19185): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
03-23 22:53:17.809: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(19185): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
```

Comment: State 8 is `PREPARED`. You're only allowed to call `pause()` when the player is in a `STARTED` state, i.e. after you've successfully called `start()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use simple if-check to handle the pausing. Try this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/jaihind.mp3"));
if(mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.pause();
} else {
    mp.start();
}
```

**Note:**

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(...);
```

is already preparing the MediaPlayer returned, so you cannot call `prepare` (or its variants) again (and there is no need for onPreparedListener as well).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use this

```
 public class Sound extends Activity{

MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    mp.release();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mp.release();` does the trick. [ instead of `mp.pause();` ]